# How can I convert trp video format to mpeg4?

Tags: video-conversion, high-definition, mpeg4

Has anybody had experience with converting TRP format to MPEG4 or any other format playable on a PC?

Answer (score 2):

I've looked for some options and found these:

- [TRP Converter](http://www.trpconverter.com/trp-to-mp4-converter.html) using [this guide.](http://www.isoftdownload.com/guide/how-to-convert-trp-to-mp4)
- [VideoReDo](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/VideoReDo)
- [DRV-Studio](http://www.haenlein-software.com/index.php?PHPSESSID=14dbdd2e94101dcdc0f23f9a63748840&REMARK=newSession)

Take a try.

Answer (score 0):

In a windows system I would use erightsoft.com  SUPER (and avoid the junkware on installation) For one basic reason, It could convert out every video file that I have had so far, it has at least some sort of GUI. With that one install I have not had to keep looking for new converters everytime a new file type came along. It is just a interface to FFMpeg and MEncoder.

According to the web it would work with Trp as long as the file is not corrupt or encrypted. It cares more about the file type inside than the extention on the outside.

.trp .ts .rec is just a Video Transport Stream, in mpeg2, or HD H.264 ,often AC3 audio. Further research shows that there are exisitng DVRs that use encryption, and hardware decryption